# Using the quote operator in Oracle to insert a semi-colon

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sqlplus

I have the following SQL for updating CSS in an existing table,

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

UPDATE SCHEMANAME.template
   SET body = q'[
<style type="text/css">
  #header {
    background-color:#004F5D;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
  }]'
WHERE name = 'CSS';
```

The template table has the following structure,

```
NAME    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(150)
SUBJECT NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4000)
BODY    NOT NULL CLOB
VERSION NUMBER(18)
```

However, when I run the update statement with sqlplus I receive,

```
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "height:100..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "position:r..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0042: unknown command "}]'" - rest of line ignored.
```

I'm using,

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production
```

and for Oracle,

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

It looks to me as though sqlplus is getting upset about the semicolon character at the end of the first declaration inside the header block.

I've tried issuing,

```
SET ESCAPE OFF
```

before running the update statement and the issue remains.

I can work around this by wrapping the UPDATE inside a BEGIN-END block.
Is this the only way to make this work?

**Does the quote-operator have issues with ';' within a block?**

Comment: (What does this have do do with Cascading Style Sheets? It is an SQL issue, whether the text was CSS or Klingon ... Tag `css` removed.)

Comment: Just inserting CSS into a table, thanks for your edit CBroe..

Comment: The quote-operator has no issues with the semicolon. Rather, it's a problem specific to SQL\*Plus; a semicolon right at the end of a line will give it trouble, even if it's within a quoted string (q quote mechanism or standard single-quotes make no difference). Toad and SQL Developer have no problem like this. If you must use SQL\*Plus, avoid having the semicolon at the end if you can; or escape it; or use CHR(...) instead of semicolon. Etc. (Google for the problem, you will find other ideas.)

Comment: Thanks mathguy, that makes sense and in the past we have used the CHR workaround before. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @CBroe: you could have just added the [klingon] tag. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is breaking your update statement into 4 parts -

1. `UPDATE SCHEMANAME.template
      SET body = q'[
   <style type="text/css">
     #header {
       background-color:#004F5D;`
2. `height:100px;`
3. `position:relative;`
4. `}]'`

can you please try below query

```
update SCHEMANAME.template
   SET body = '"'||chr(13)||'<style type="text/css">'||chr(13)||  '#header {'||chr(13)||    'background-color:#004F5D;'||chr(13)||    'height:100px;'||chr(13)||  'position:relative;'||chr(13)||  '}"'
WHERE name = 'CSS';
```

**Instead of quote , I am using chr(13) -  for new line.**

Comment: @mathguy suggested this too and it worked. I was hoping there was a "better" way, but it looks like it's just an SQLPlus thing.

Comment: @James , As mathguy suggested you just use chr for semicolon alone in your update string literal.That will also work fine.